# SQLite remove database error

Tags: c++, sqlite, qt, qtsql

I have widget which connects to database:

```
Widget::Widget(QWidget *parent)
{
    QString databaseName = "name";
    QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");
    db.setDatabaseName(databaseName);
    db.setHostName("localhost");
    if(!db.open())
        qDebug()<<"ret error";
}
```

Now I want to delete database connection after widget close (currently I get warnings like:  `QSqlDatabasePrivate::removeDatabase: connection 'qt_sql_default_connection is still in use...`). I' ve read some topics and tried to evaluate some solution from them but none works for me. My code:

```
void Widget::closeEvent(QCloseEvent *e)
{
    QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::database();
    QString connection = db.connectionName();
    db.close();
    QSqlDatabase::removeDatabase(connection);
    qDebug()<<"error: "<<db.lastError().text();
}
```

Error I get is: `Driver not loaded Driver not loaded`

What is the correct way to do this?

Edit:

another method:

```
void Widget::someMethod()
{
    QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::database();
    QSqlQuery query(db);
    query.exec("some query");
}
```

Comment: Do you have your sqlite library installed in your system?

Comment: Yes, everything works I can add data. Call queries and see it in table view. Only problem is with closing. Error is returned in closeEvent().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try giving a connection name parameter(2nd parameter) in addDatabase() , that should solve your problem.

Here is the modified code you could try:

```
Widget::Widget(QWidget *parent)
{
    QString databaseName = "name";
    QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE", "test_db_connection" );
    db.setDatabaseName(databaseName);
    db.setHostName("localhost");
    if(!db.open())
        qDebug()<<"ret error";
}
```

Here is a complete working code from my machine for sqlite database which you can use as reference:

```
local_db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE","localdb");
local_db.setDatabaseName("localdb.sqlite");
local_db_query = QSqlQuery(local_db);
local_db_query.prepare( "SELECT * FROM sample_table" );
local_db_query.exec();
```

Comment: Added it and get: "`QSqlQuery::exec: database not open`". Database is not even opened.

Comment: Please use the sqllite file name as database name and check. I mean use "name.sqlite" or what ever is your sqlite file name in your computer

Comment: This helped. I've already accepted the answer. If you could explain it little more would be nice.

Comment: In addDatabase function if we dont give connection name i.e. 2nd parameter, default connection is used. So that causes the warning. I hope it explains. Pls let me know if you have any specific query/doubt.